# After creating pdf, redirect to index page in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am implementing PDF file generation and I have completed it using this link:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kalileo/2010/06/08/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and-tcpdf

After generating PDF, it calls another function that performs update of my database. And should redirect to index page. I have done my database update. Only problem in redirecting to index page. When I am redirecting to index page PDF logic is not implementing.

I think it is because of i have set layout for pdf so both index page and pdf creation not works one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set the PDF layout as stated on the Bakery, you can not redirect the user.
The PDF layout sent a header to your browser that states PDF content is coming it's way. A HTTP redirect is not PDF content, so this will not work.

If you want the PDF generation to be done on the background and not "on-the-fly" in the user's browser window, just drop the PDF layout and use your 'default' layout instead. You can then just call `$this->redirect` from your controller.

Comment: I've tried this and I get the redirect but no PDF generated. :S